# add column with autodate when inserting new rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called samples that looks like this

```
Column        Type       Comment
id            int(11)   Auto Increment  
nvname        text  
sample        text  
client        text  
project       text  
model         text     NULL 
pathology     text     NULL 
treatment     text     NULL 
location      text     NULL 
notes         text     NULL
```

I would need to add a column date at the end that automatically adds date of insertion can that be done?
if not should I use trigger to copy to another table with that information while inserting?

Comment: Use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Maybe you are looking [for](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).  Add this column definition, or something like it, to your table definition.

```sql
    insert_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You can also add this column definition if you want to know when the row was most recently updated.

```sql
    update_timestamp TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then, if you don't mention the column's name when doing an INSERT or UPDATE, it gets handled automatically, robustly, and far more efficiently than a trigger.

Pretty sweet feature, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)` in next way:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    created_at date NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
);
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Test name');
```

[SQL online fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/ba653b446d9d6b78795aa33f1bdc2f3b/)

Result:

```
+====+===========+============+
| id | name      | created_at |
+====+===========+============+
| 1  | Test name | 2022-01-03 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```